# Swift sender for overriden prepare method

Tags: ios, swift

I learn iOS development using eBook iOS Development Essentials and there is a part about Master-Detail interface. I should change code within

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
```

method. The problem is I have only

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

method. Changing sender manually to AnyObject does not work - results in:

```
Method does not override any method from its superclass
```

Since the method is not working as expected, I wonder if it might be related to the sender.

Comment: The book is outdated, it was changed to `Any?` in swift 3

Answer (score 2):

You should override this method:

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

The error:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

occurs, because `UIViewController` (*superclass*) does not have `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)` method, so nothing to override.

Method `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)` changed to `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` in Xcode 8 beta 6.

Answer (score 0):

The correct signature for a UIViewController `prepare(for:sender:)` method is

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

If you're reading a book that shows

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
```

It's wrong. (In Swift, functions where the parameters have different types are considered different functions. It looks like the type of the sender parameter changed recently, so your tutorial's code is probably a little out-of-date.)

You should simply change `AnyOject?` to `Any?`in the function definition.